# Linux weird problem touch : command not found?

Tags: linux, vi, touch

I occurred a really weired problem, which is touch : command not found.

I was going to create a blank file, so I type the touch command which didn't work.

I'm running centOS 5.

Any ideas?

BTW: the vi command also not found.

Comment: Type `echo $PATH`, what do you see?  Or try "/bin/echo $PATH"

Answer (score 4):

You probably temporarily messed up your path.  It may be enough to do:

```
exec /bin/bash
```

Then you can try `touch`, etc. to make sure things are normal.

If that doesn't work, the PATH definition is wrong in one of your system files.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find the command manually. It will be a file named touch and on my current system it is /bin/touch. You can find it by with locate touch  or even find / -name touch. If you find it with locate and it isn't where it says that it should be, that could mean that it was recently moved or deleted.

Once you find the command, make sure that it is in your PATH with echo $PATH. If all this works, try specifying the path and command together (i.e. /bin/touch foo). You may also want to check your aliases to see if there is anything there messing things up.

As an observation, you mention that vi isn't working either. In my system, both vi and touch are in /bin and not /usr/bin. Check to see if you are able to run other commands from there.

Answer (score 1):

I made the mistake of overriding my PATH in a script;

```
while read -r PATH; do
  touch "${PATH}";
done < <(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r "${COMMIT_ID}")
```

The `read -r PATH` bit cleared the path to the touch binary.

Fix was a simple rename:

```
while read -r GIT_PATH; do
```

Comment: In general you should choose [lowercase (or at least not-all-uppercase) names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618). If `GIT_PATH` was an environment variable (e.g. exported in `/etc/profile`) that matters for some tool you're going to use, then the tool could misbehave. With `git_path` you should be safer from such mishaps because sane tools use uppercase names for variables. Not entirely safe though, e.g. `zsh` [uses `path` along with `PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/532148/108618). Picking a safe name takes some knowledge of your environment and your shell.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
type touch
```

It may tell you that the `touch` command is at `/usr/bin/touch` and if so:

```
/usr/bin/touch ...
```

Comment: it tells me: "-bash: type: touch: not found"

Answer (score 0):

You might have unintentionally deleted **touch**

*You can reinstall by **copying** **it from another computer*** **to**:

```
/bin/
```

using command: `sudo cp path/to/copied/touch /bin`